# We've been getting more UX questions... what are our procedures on handling?

Tags: discussion

Lately I've noticed we have been getting more UX questions but I didn't know what we should consider as GD or UX.  I do know we committed with UX to migrate all icon questions over but lately I've seen a few app questions come through.  So do we have any guidelines yet on how to decide which is in scope and not?

Comment: Do you remember a couple of them to add as examples?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a whole to do short of 'play it by ear'. GD and UX overlap quite a bit, so I think there will always be questions that straddle the two.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to look for a few examples that I thought had elements of UX in them.

But before I forget, here's a suggestion:

We could try to extract the essence of both parts of the question (if possible), and then edit the question to focus on the GD aspect and then create and migrate the UX part as a separate question in the same users name.

I don't know how realistically achievable this is, or how widely applicable. It would require communication between the OP, community and mods which is a lot to ask.

If anything it could be one of many options for dealing with an issue that has to be dealt with on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: That's very complex. It doesn't sound like a realistic solution.

Comment: The catch here is that you often can't separate them. GD and UX influence each other highly and to separate them will often take away all necessary context.

Comment: That is an **extremely** good point. ;( Now we know of one way that probably won't work for most cases. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Dominic commented, Graphic Design and User Experience overlap very much.

A few differentiation guidelines that might be worth having a look at:

1. **Can the partially-UX question be interpreted in a way that meets the [on-topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) guidelines?** *- If yes, move on, if not, mark off-topic.*
2. **If so, is it a multi-part question? Can some parts be removed in order to salvage the question?** *- If yes, put on hold and move on, if not, mark off-topic.*
3. **Did the user make the necessary changes?** *-  If yes, good. If not, oh well.*

If we just do this, following the guidelines that are **already defined by the great founding fathers of Graphic Design**, we should be able to handle telling the difference between what is appropriate, and what isn't.